# Rails deployemnt Issue,rake task not detect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, rake-task

remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     translation missing: en.Slack.Channels.MissingVariable
remote:  !     /tmp/build_00c6e226/config/application.rb:15:in `block in <class:Application>' remote:  !     /tmp/build_00c6e226/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/slack-ruby-client-1.0.0/lib/slack/config.rb:18:in` configure'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_00c6e226/config/application.rb:13:in `<class:Application>' remote:  !     /tmp/build_00c6e226/config/application.rb:11:in` module:SparechangeApi'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_00c6e226/config/application.rb:9:in `<main>' remote:  !     /tmp/build_00c6e226/Rakefile:4:in` require_relative'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_00c6e226/Rakefile:4:in `'

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Heroku throws an issue on deployment about assets. You can precompile assets and push it to Heroku.

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

**Update:**

In case of it doesn't work, make sure to add `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES` env. to your server.

Make it `enabled` or `true` nor anything :)

Because in Rails <5.1 production.rb has

`config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?`

> Heroku: App -> Settings -> "Reveal Config Vars"

[image]

Comment: Dude stop copying/pasting this solution to every version of this problem. It doesn't always work. Read the error log carefully. It has nothing to do with precompiling assets